# componentDidMount not rendering my data initially, only on componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to React and I'm sure there is probably an easier way to do this but I am trying to load all events that belong to a specific group whose ID is passed to the Events components as a prop. The Events get changed every time a new group is selected using the componentDidUpdate and the getDerivedStateFromProps. That functionality works but the problem I am having is that on componentDidMount I am rendered an empty array of events so nothing shows up on the first click of a group but they show up on the second (and on).

Here is the Events component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardActionArea, CardMedia, CardContent, Typography, 
CardActions, Button, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import firebase from '../config/Fire'; 

export class Events extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        currentGroup: '',
        eventHold: [],
        loaded: false
    }
    this.formatDate = this.formatDate.bind(this);
    this.loadEvents = this.loadEvents.bind(this);
}
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({currentGroup: this.props.currentGroup}, () => {this.loadEvents(this.state.currentGroup)})
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(prevState.currentGroup !== this.state.currentGroup){
        const newGroup = this.state.currentGroup;
        this.setState({currentGroup: newGroup}, () => {
            this.loadEvents(newGroup);
        });
    }
}
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
    if(nextProps.currentGroup!==prevState.currentGroup){
        return {currentGroup : nextProps.currentGroup};
    }
    else
        return null;
}
loadEvents(groupid){
    const groupRef = firebase.database().ref('groups').child(groupid).child('events');
    var tempIdHold =[];
    groupRef.on('value', snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(snap => {
            tempIdHold.push(snap.key)
        })
    })
    const rootRef = firebase.database().ref('events');
    const tempEventHold =[];
    tempIdHold.forEach(event => { 
        rootRef.child(event).on('value', snap => {
            let newEvent = {
                id: snap.key,
                title: snap.val().title,
                description: snap.val().description,
                date: snap.val().date
            };
            tempEventHold.push(newEvent);
        })
    }); 
    this.setState({
        eventHold: tempEventHold,
        loaded:true
    })
}
formatDate = ( date ) => {
    const year = date.substring(0,4);
    const month = date.substring(5,7);
    const day = date.substring(8,10);
    const dateObj = new Date(year, month-1, day);

    return dateObj.toLocaleDateString();
}
render(){
    console.log(this.state.loaded);
    if(this.state.loaded){
        return(
            <div>
                <Grid container 
                    spacing={24} 
                    justify="center"
                    alignItems="center">
                {this.state.eventHold.map(event => 
                    <Grid item key={event.id}>
                        <Card>
                            <CardActionArea>
                            <CardMedia
                                component="img"
                                alt=""
                                height="140"
                                image= "blank"
                                title=""
                            />
                            <CardContent>
                                <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                                {event.title}
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography component="p">
                                {this.formatDate(event.date)}
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography component="p">
                                {event.id}
                                </Typography>
                                <Typography component="p">
                                {this.state.currentGroup}
                                </Typography>
                            </CardContent>
                            </CardActionArea>
                            <CardActions>
                            <Button size="small" color="primary">
                                Like
                            </Button>
                            <Button size="small" color="primary">
                                Comment
                            </Button>
                            <Button size="small" color="primary">
                                Learn More
                            </Button>
                            </CardActions>
                        </Card>
                    </Grid>
                )}
                </Grid>
            </div>
        )
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif" />
        </div>
      )
}
```

}

Quick explanation of the loadEvents(): I am retrieving all eventIDs from the currentGroup (the group that should be rendered on screen) under the "groups" Firebase node and saving those to a temp array which I iterate through to retrieve the event data from the "events" Firebase node and push to a temp event array which is then pushed to the eventHold state array.

Comment: Do you need `currentGroup` in state? Why not just reference it from props? Then in `componentDidMount` just call `this.loadEvents()` and in `componentDidUpdate` compare `prevProps` to `this.props`. Also, I'm not sure you even need `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

Comment: it's better to ```setState({currentGroup: this.props.currentGroup}``` in ```componentDidMount``` instead of setting it in ```this.state```, as states are compared by react and setting it twice is of no use & doesn't ```re Render()``` the component.

Answer (score 1):

> "setState() does not always immediately update the component.  It may batch or defer the update until later." , [React docs setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

`ComponentDidMount()` runs only once after `render()` while the `ComponentDidUpdate()` runs after every update to state. [State and LifeCycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

You must `console.log()` your array in `render()` method, as setState doesn't always change state on time (that line of code), instead it queues all `setState()` calls and updates just before calling `render()`. `console.log()` your array in `render()` as that value will be rendered, it will help you understand the problem.

Comment: The render shows the same problem which makes sense, I have an empty array on the first click but a filled one on the second. Is there a way to pre-load the array to the component? I know componentWillMount is deprecated now but is there something like it that I can use or some other way I can work around it?

Comment: Use Conditional Rendering https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html , or use some boolean e.g ```isLoaded```, set it to ```true``` when you ```setState()``` of your array, in render use ```if(isLoaded) { // render your component/array } else { //render something else or may be a predefined component/array}```.

Comment: You can also define ```defaultProps``` for a component. Have a look at this https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops .

Comment: I updated the question so you can see the render, I've tried using conditional rendering but that still doesn't work. And I can't use defaultProps because it is data from firebase which is different from user to user so a default won't cover that. Is there something wrong with this code? It really makes no sense to me why it won't reload the render once loaded = true.

Comment: Why aren't you assigning ```currentGroup : this.props.currentGroup``` in constructor?

Comment: Either make assignments in constructor or directly use props when calling loadEvents, ```setState()``` instantly doesn't update the state(if there are other setState() calls like i see in ```loadEvents()``` ).

Comment: So do one of these. (1-) Assign ```currentGroup``` in constructor and only call ```this.loadEvents(this.state.currentGroup)``` in ```ComponentDidMount```. (2-) Just change ```this.state.currentGroup``` in loadEvents to ```this.props.currentGroup```.

Comment: Still no luck with those.. In my code I have a console.log in the render that shows this.state.loaded. This on load goes from false to true almost instantly. It is catching that loaded is changing but not re-rendering the Grid on the state change. Is there a way to force reload?

Comment: hi @BenCavenagh the grid you are rendering must be a controlled component. Pass it the array via props and don't keep any state. better if you make it a stateless functional component. I encountered the same recently so i thought i shall let you know.